# How to implement undo/redo functionality for KovaJS in react?

Tags: konvajs

What's the best way to implement undo/redo functionality for KovaJS in react?

I see that each node has toObject() method used for serialisation of each canvas node. One easy implementation would be to serialize the object on each modification and push it into a array of changes. And once the user taps Undo/Redo, to try and rebuild the canvas from that array.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like it might be viable. You will though lose any js handles to the canvas shapes in an undo - redo, so if you need to use events or any kind of js manipulation of the shapes you will have the overhead of re-connecting them. That said, you would need to do that however you handle your undo/redo, so serialisation may well make sense if the stage does not have an excessive amount of shapes. Interested to know how you get on.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) events will be required so i'll need to come up with a solution to reconnect them, something to think about 

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `toObject()` if you are using React.

It will be much simpler to save a history of the state (react component state, redux state or whatever state you are using). And implement undo/redo with it.

Simplest demo for undo:

```
let history = [{
  x: 20,
  y: 20
}];
let historyStep = 0;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    position: history[0]
  };

  handleUndo = () => {
    if (historyStep === 0) {
      return;
    }
    historyStep -= 1;
    this.setState({
      position: history[historyStep]
    });
  };
  handleDragEnd = e => {
    history.slice(0, historyStep);
    history = history.concat({
      x: e.target.x(),
      y: e.target.y()
    });
    historyStep += 1;
    console.log(history[history.length - 1]);
    this.setState({
      position: history[history.length - 1]
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Text text="undo" onClick={this.handleUndo} />
          <Rect
            x={this.state.position.x}
            y={this.state.position.y}
            width={50}
            height={50}
            fill="black"
            draggable
            onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}
          />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/3x3rwnlykp

Comment: Thanks for the reply  I'm actually planning to implement undo redo for a broader array of actions (filters, transforms, adding/removing components). For an initial implementation i would serialize the whole stage on each action and rebuild it when undo/redo is applied.