# How to implement undo/redo functionality for KovaJS,when i drag the Image or scale the stage in react

Tags: konvajs

I want to implement undo/redo functionality for konvas in react project,when dragged the Image or stage.
but i do not have any ideas to do that,I've done some attempts. Firstly, i find  a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406640/how-to-implement-undo-redo-functionality-for-kovajs-in-react),but the demo for that question is too simple，i still do not know how to do that, Secondly, i want to serialize the stage, store it in react state ,and deserialize stage when users taps Undo/Redo, like the [konvas.js docs](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/data_and_serialization/Complex_Load.html) ,but it is too difficult for me to do that, above is my question,I would appreciate it, who tell me how to do that,